# dGrid: How do you add blank rows to the grid?

Tags: html, dojo, dgrid

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/92bmhr3d/) over here.

[image: dGrid Blank Row]
There is a row (no.4) in the the store having empty/null values, but the grid display appears to be collapsed.

code snippet:

```
function(Grid, Memory) {
    var data = [

        { id: 1, name: 'Peter', age:24 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Paul', age: 30 },
         { id: 3, name: 'Mary', age:46 },
        { id: '', name: '', age:'' }
    ];
    var store = new Memory({ data: data });
    var options = {
        columns: [
           /*{ field: 'id',  label: 'ID' },*/
            { field: 'name', label: 'Name' },
            { field: 'age', label: 'Age' }

        ],
        store: store
    };

    new Grid(options, 'gridcontainer');
}
```

I would like to have blank rows in the grid with the same height as other populated rows.

Is it possible in dGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason why blank rows do not have the same height as other rows is that dGrid doesn't actually set a specific height that a row should have. In situations where a cell may need a 2nd row, then the cell would grow in height. If you want a set height, you can add a css attribute to your fiddle that does something like:

```
#gridcontainer .dgrid-content .dgrid-cell {
  height: 24px;
}
```